# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException even after adding set property webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting **Exception:**

```
in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:The path to the 
 driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver 
 system property;
 for more information, 
  see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. 
  The latest version can be downloaded from 
  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at SeleniumFirefox.main(SeleniumFirefox.java:11)
```

Below is the code used **SeleniumFirefox.java**:

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

 public class SeleniumFirefox {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver.driver",
           "C://Users//balwinder//Desktop//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

/*try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}*/

   }}
```

Comment: Some problem in chromedriver.exe i guess. Get new Exe from seleniumhq. Don't keep it in user/desktop . Keep it in D drive and then try.

Comment: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/

Comment: Thank You @KishanPatel but it give me same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `webdriver.chrome.driver` instead of `webdriver.chromedriver.driver`

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver.driver",
           "C://Users//balwinder//Desktop//chromedriver.exe");
```

Should be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
           "C:\\Users\\balwinder\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
```

OR

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
           "C:/Users/balwinder/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
```

**NOTE**: it will work only if you are first setting the system property and  then instantiating chrome driver..

Comment: Hi , i just tried with the above change and getting the same error!!

Comment: please refer updated answer, you have wrong path separator as well.

Answer (score 1):

The PATH to the chromedriver.exe file was not set properly.
Download the chrome driver zip file and extract it to a folder, go to the extracted folder, copy the path of that folder by clicking on the PATH tab, and explicitly the write .exe file name (.exe is mandatory to write).

**Note: Separator between folders should be \ (backslash)**

For example please see below:

**System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Softwares\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");**

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without `System.setProperty` is simply add folder with `chromedriver.exe` to PATH
(if someone don't know how - google "set path variable").

To check that this approach works you may put `chromedriver.exe` to `C:\Windows\System32` folder.