# I'm trying to launch a chromedriver in seleniumwebdriver even i give the right path its show error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class sampledr {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.setProperty(" webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\chromedriver.exe" );
    WebDriver d= new ChromeDriver();
```

It's show illegal state exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404446/getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-even-after-adding-set-property-webdriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException even after adding set property webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404446/getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-even-after-adding-set-property-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost perfect but have a issue. When you mention any **`Key-Value`** pair through **`System.setProperty`**, these values are **`String`** and shouldn't contain any spaces within. So you need to update the line as :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\chromedriver.exe" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class sampledr {
public WebDriver driver;  //it creates the driver object 
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\chromedriver.exe" ); //set driver path
   wd = new ChromeDriver(); //Call driver
driver.get("https://www.google.com");  //open site
```